# placing an image in the camera view in android

Tags: android, camera

I want to place an image at the middle camera view in the android.

I am using following code to open the camera

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mIntent.putExtra
(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
startActivityForResult(mIntent, PHOTO_SELECT);
```

and its working.But i dont know how to place an image.

Thanks in advanxe.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no possibility, if you start the Camera via Intent! 
The System is just searching for an Application, which does your requested "job" (i.e. in your case the Camera-Application).

You have to render previewImages of your Camera to a SurfaceView. After that, you can render your Images to this SurfaceView